# Как вывести картинку в угол экрана

Tags: delphi

Добрый день.Можно ли вывести определённую картинку на монитор в левый верхний угол? Если да, то как?Желательно использовать компонент TImage. Заранее благодарен.
Необходимо, чтобы картинка отображалась поверх всех окон, но при этом не мешала работать(чтобы работать и "любоваться" на картинку))))

Answer (score 1):

без подробностей первое что приходит на ум:
создаешь форму с параметрами BorderStyle = bsNone; WindowState=wsMaximized;
на ней TImage с загруженой картинкой в свойстве Pucture и вуаля

Comment: Плюс к этому добавить FormStyle=fsStayOnTop

Answer (score 0):

Создаём на форме объект Timage. Добавляем в него картинку.
В коде программы указываем чтобы размеры картинки совпадали с размерами
объекта Timage (свойства height, width) также с размерами формы...
Делаем форму в левом верхнем углу (свойства Top, Left)
Удачи.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно получить доступ к экрану и на нём нарисовать картинку поверх всех окон, то вот код:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  ScreenDC: HDC;  // дескриптор экрана
  ScreenCanvas: TCanvas; // канва экрана
  BitMap: TBitMap; // битмап, если у Image AutoSize=False
begin
  ScreenDC:=GetDC(0);
  ScreenCanvas:=TCanvas.Create; // создаю канву
  ScreenCanvas.Handle:=ScreenDC; // передаю дескриптор экрана
If (Image.AutoSize) Then
    ScreenCanvas.Draw(0, 0, Image.Picture.Graphic) // рисую картинку целиком
  Else
    Begin  // рисую кусок картинки
      BitMap:=TBitMap.Create;
      BitMap.Assign(Image.Picture.Bitmap); // загружаю в битмап
      // подгоняю размеры битмапа
      BitMap.Width:=Image.Width;
      BitMap.Height:=Image.Height;
      ScreenCanvas.Draw(0, 0, BitMap); // рисую кусок
      BitMap.Free;
    End;
// уничтожаю всё, что я раньше создавал
  ReleaseDC(0, ScreenDC);
  ScreenCanvas.Free;
end;
```

Если поводить по этой картинке окном (или развернуть окно на весь экран) или попасть мышью на какой-нибудь ярлык, то часть картинки сотрётся, таким образом, её можно будет стереть целиком. Если у Image AutoSize=False, а Stretch=True, то нарисуется только тот кусок, который был бы виден при Stretch=False.